# Amazon S3 in transit security

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a project where users will upload files into Amazon AWS S3 buckets my java code will use AmazonS3EncryptionClient to download the object from the buckets and process them.While many sources are there about encryption at rest over the web little is present about securing while in transit only that S3 supports SSL.So my question is how to enable SSL both for users who are uploading the files and also when my java code is downloading from the bucket?

Comment: I'm missing how users upload to the bucket - can you elaborate?  On the download side, as long as you're not forcing HTTP, the default is HTTPS.  Unless you're specifically calling something like [withProtocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#withProtocol(com.amazonaws.Protocol)) you will be using HTTPS.

Comment: Hey stdunbar, 
Thanks for the reply.
The user will be using Amazon S3 console to upload the files. They will have an IAM user account and use that to upload the files to the S3 bucket. Similar to what has been shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=231&v=-5MPXHvKDnc.